# Hive Metastore tries to create a Derby connection instead of MySQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

I am using Hive 0.11 and Metastore in local mode. When I try to start the Metastore daemon, it exits after spitting the following error  message:

2013-11-21 08:47:19.541 GMT Thread[main,5,main] java.io.FileNotFoundException: derby.log (Permission denied)

2013-11-21 08:47:19.646 GMT Thread[main,5,main] Cleanup action starting

ERROR XBM0H: Directory /metastore_db cannot be created.

This is my  [hive-site.xml](http://pastebin.com/dD8QGAm6). I am using MySQL as  Metastore storage. What I don't understand is why is Hive trying to create   metastore_db  locally.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Set `hive.metastore.local` property as `false`. (Removed as of Hive 0.10: If hive.metastore.uris is empty local mode is assumed, remote otherwise)

Set `hive.metastore.uris` property with valid uri (Host and port for the Thrift metastore server)

For eg:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://hap-db:9083</value>
  <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
</property>
```

Comment: Suresh, I am using version 0.11 for Hive. So I do not have hive.metastore.local param in my config file. the hive.metastore.uris param is set for Metastore in local mode. So I had kept the value as thrift://0.0.0.0:9083. I also tried with commenting that parameter out. Hive still goes to Derby.

Answer (score -3):

Hi faced similar issue on hive 0.14. I had installed hive as root user and was trying to run hive services as a sudo user i use for all hadoop jobs.
Once i changed the installation owner to sudo and restarted it worked . so this error is mostly related to file permissions issue.